# How to translate the company name?

Tags: word-order, translation, proper-nouns

Here is the situation:

I know one Russian woman named Oxana Volkova. She is a doctor dermatologist/cosmetologist and she has her own clinic.
We made a bet: **How to translate her clinic name?**

---

In Russia it looks like this:

> Центр медицинской косметологии Оксаны Волковой

If I translate it step by step we will get:

> The Centre of Medical Cosmetology (created/founded) by Oxana Volkova

But I feel it's wrong and I am not sure which one is correct:

1. The Oxana Volkova Medical Cosmetology Centre
2. Dr. Oxana Volkova Medical Cosmetology Centre
3. Oxana Volkova Centre of Medical Cosmetology
4. The Oxana Volkova Centre for Medical Cosmetology
5. Other(s) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would call it

> Oxana Volkova Medical Cosmetology Center

Answer (score 1):

This is what makes translation fun: there is almost always a degree of *interpretation* in every *translation*, so the "correct" translation is the one that the clinic owner, Dr. Volkova, likes best.

Personally, based on other clinic names I've seen, I would expect the following, but it's really a personal preference on her part:

> The Volkova Center for Dermatological Cosmetology

Answer (score 0):

In English, it is very common to use more lengthened premodifiers in a phrase. The most idiomatic options would probably be either *Oxana Volkova Medical Cosmetology Center* or *Oxana Volkova Center for Medical Cosmetology*. The first would probably be better than the latter.

This is often done in names, here are a few other examples:

> - Oxford University
> - Cambridge Online English Dictionary
> - Whipps Cross University Hospital

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget the genitive:

> Oxana Volkova's Center of Medical Cosmetology

I wonder if it should not be:

> Oksana Volkova's Center of Medical Cosmetology

(the difference is in the spelling of the first name)